# Open Bootstrap Modal from an Angular component without using ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a Bootstrap Modal from an Angular component **without using ng-bootstrap**(not updated to Angular 14 yet).

I am using bootstrap 4.6, and I have integrated it by installing the npm bootstrap, popper and jquery respectively.

*package.json*

```
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
```

I also configured *angular.json* the following way:

```
 "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        ]
```

In the component I have a modal object (html):

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" #Modal tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">.
   ...</div>
```

while on an event in the component .ts, I try:

```
$('#Modal').modal('show')
```

but unfortunately, I get the following exception:

```
core.mjs:7635 ERROR TypeError:.modal is not a function
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this kind of exception and open the modal correctly?

Is there also a way to avoid using **jquery** and using directly **@ViewChild**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/javascript/), `all plugins depend on jQuery`, so you won't be able to avoid using jQuery.

While it's not recommended to use jQuery and Angular together, it's possible in principle. As you already added it in your `package.json`, you just need to declare to jQuery symbol using `declare var $: any;`. Read [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular-when-you-absolutely-have-to-42c8b6a37ff9) for further information.

However, I would suggest to avoid using jQuery and Angular both in one project. Have a look at Bootstrap Version 5.x to be independent of jQuery (`Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery`): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/ – in my opinion, this would fit best to your described use case.

Comment: So how do you actually open the model from Angular?

Comment: When using Bootstrap and Angular, it is recommended to use "Angular powered Bootstrap" such as [this library](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). However, if you need to rely on jQuery, follow [this guide](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular-when-you-absolutely-have-to-42c8b6a37ff9).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5

use the @ViewChild

```
<button type="button" #test class="btn btn-primary invisible" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#android-modal">Launch demo modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="android-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="android-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="android-modalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the ts file get the Button element with the ViewChild and use the click event

**in order to get the element you have to implement the AfterViewInit**

```
export class ModalComponent implements AfterViewInit

  @ViewChild("test") modal: ElementRef | undefined
ngAfterViewInit(): void { this.modal?.nativeElement.click(); };
```